# Dropdown checkboxes and unchecked parents element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I'm keen on jquery and that is why I'm trying to develop myself on it.

I got some issue to fix but my brain is stopped right know because of working a lot of for my real job.

[`demo`](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/vGyYyN)

the link that you see is my project to develop myself.but last thing I cannot do that is how to toggle dropdown my checkboxes which has got child ul elements. I mean I want to dropdown my nested checkboxs

and if I click parent elements child elements has to be checked and opened (so far it's okay) but parent elements not has to be checked.I mean I don't want to parent element be checked if has got child.

my codes

html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>No Title</title>
</head>
<body> 

    <div class="new-checkbox">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="input1">
        <label for="input1">kategori <strong>(1)</strong>
        </label>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input11">
            <label for="input11">kategori<strong>(11)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input12">
            <label for="input12">kategori <strong>(12)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input13">
            <label for="input13">kategori <strong>(13)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="input2">
        <label for="input2">kategori <strong>(2)</strong>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="input3">
        <label for="input3">kategori <strong>(3)</strong>
        </label>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input31">
            <label for="input31">kategori <strong>(31)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input32">
            <label for="input32">kategori <strong>(32)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input33">
            <label for="input33">kategori <strong>(33)</strong>
            </label>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="input331">
                <label for="input331">kategori <strong>(331)</strong>
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="input332">
                <label for="input332">kategori <strong>(332)</strong>
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="input333">
                <label for="input333">kategori <strong>(333)</strong>
                </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- new checkbox-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.anitur.com.tr/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" ></script>

</body>
</html>
```

css

```
.new-checkbox ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font: normal 11px/16px"Segoe UI", Arial, Sans-serif;
}

.new-checkbox ul:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.new-checkbox ul li {
  margin: 3px 0;
}

.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.new-checkbox label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  content: "\00a0";
  display: inline-block;
  font: 16px/1em sans-serif;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 2px .25em 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: solid 1px #1375b3;
  color: #1375b3;
  opacity: .50;
}

.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  background: #fff;
  color: #1375b3;
  content: "\2714";
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) inset;
  opacity: 1;
}

.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.new-checkbox ul li:before {
  content: "\25b6";
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  color: #e74c3c;
  font-size: 8px;
  line-height: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.new-checkbox li {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"][id]:checked ~ li::before {
  content: "\25bc";
}

.new-checkbox li ul {
  display: none;
}

.new-checkbox li.has-checked > ul {
  display: block;
}
.addDownicon li::before {
    content: "\25bc" !important;
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.new-checkbox input[type=checkbox]').on("change", function() {
    var checked = this.checked,
      $li = $(this).parent();
    $li.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', checked).parent().toggleClass('has-checked', checked);

    $li.parentsUntil('.new-checkbox', 'li').each(function() {
      var $checks = $(this).find('ul input[type=checkbox]');
      $(this).children('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', !$checks.filter(':not(:checked)').length);

      $(this).toggleClass('has-checked', $checks.is(':checked'));
    });

  });


});
```

Comment: "but parent elements not has to be checked.I mean I don't want to parent element be checked if has got child." could you rewrite or explain this? I don't understand.

Comment: Could you rewrite your question? This way it's really unclear of what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: if I click parent elements my parent elements and child elements being checked..but I want my parents elements not be checked to if it has child elements (sorry about my english) @JohannesJander

Comment: So if I click on a parent element with children, it should stay unchecked, but if I click on a parent element without children, it should be checked?

Comment: @user3398922 I want to make dropdown  for my nested checkbox like this http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/tree/tree4_demo.html

Comment: yes @JohannesJander that's right exactly

Comment: no one understand right ? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must confess I am still not 100% sure I understand - probably because I am not an English native speaker and have a harder time reading complicated issues, but I tried:

You could add a function that looks for children and sets a class `has-children` if there are children:

```
$('.new-checkbox ul')
   .find("input[type=checkbox]")
   .parent()
   .each(function(i, elem) {
     if ($(elem).find("ul").length > 0) {
       $(this).addClass('has-children');
     }
});
```

Then add a CSS rule that takes away the artificial checkboxes on those `<input>` tags where the parent `<li>` has the class `has-children` set:

```
.new-checkbox .has-children > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  content: " ";
}
```

I have created [an updated JSBin demo](https://jsbin.com/fedoxakoge/1/edit?css,js,output) that shows the result.

Comment: I'm grateful for you yes exactly right but if I click label no necessary be checked but if I clicked label it has to be checked and if checkboxes doesn't work well if I click second time checkbox is not to be toggle (checked,unchecked)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand :/

Comment: your demo link..when I clicked child checkbox they are not being unchecked or checked again :/

Comment: example : http://experiments.wemakesites.net/css3-treeview-with-multiple-node-selection.html

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean, I updated the demo: https://jsbin.com/fedoxakoge/1/edit?css,js,output

Comment: yes @johannes as you understand it's working great :) but I have

checkbox | label (side by side)

and if I clicked checkbox it has to be checked but if I clicked label it musn't be checked that's all :/

Comment: That's not easy to do. You hide the checkboxes and show the fake boxes as `label:before`. Therefore, the checkbox-change listener only works because clicks on the label (or label:before) trigger a change in the checkbox. No idea how to exclude a label click but include a label:before click without a lot of ugly and brittle code.

Comment: ok..how about addClass ? how I add class which my checkbox doesn't have child ?

Comment: Use the if-condition in my code: `if ($(elem).find("ul").length > 0) {
       $(this).addClass('has-children');
     } else {$(this).addClass('no-children');}`