# How to unchecked nested checkbox using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As you can see, I have nested checkboxes they work very well but if I click on the parent label my parent checkbox hasn't to be checked. how is impossible ?

[image: Tree-view]

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>No Title</title>
</head>
<body> 

    <div class="new-checkbox">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="input1">
        <label for="input1">kategori <strong>(1)</strong>
        </label>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input11">
            <label for="input11">kategori<strong>(11)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input12">
            <label for="input12">kategori <strong>(12)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input13">
            <label for="input13">kategori <strong>(13)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="input2">
        <label for="input2">kategori <strong>(2)</strong>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="input3">
        <label for="input3">kategori <strong>(3)</strong>
        </label>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input31">
            <label for="input31">kategori <strong>(31)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input32">
            <label for="input32">kategori <strong>(32)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input33">
            <label for="input33">kategori <strong>(33)</strong>
            </label>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="input331">
                <label for="input331">kategori <strong>(331)</strong>
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="input332">
                <label for="input332">kategori <strong>(332)</strong>
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="input333">
                <label for="input333">kategori <strong>(333)</strong>
                </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- new checkbox-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.anitur.com.tr/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" ></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.new-checkbox ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font: normal 11px/16px"Segoe UI", Arial, Sans-serif;
}

.new-checkbox ul:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.new-checkbox ul li {
  margin: 3px 0;
}

.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.new-checkbox label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  content: "\00a0";
  display: inline-block;
  font: 16px/1em sans-serif;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 2px .25em 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: solid 1px #1375b3;
  color: #1375b3;
  opacity: .50;
}

.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  background: #fff;
  color: #1375b3;
  content: "\2714";
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) inset;
  opacity: 1;
}

.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.new-checkbox ul li:before {
  content: "\25b6";
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  color: #e74c3c;
  font-size: 8px;
  line-height: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.new-checkbox li {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"][id]:checked ~ li::before {
  content: "\25bc";
}

.new-checkbox li ul {
  display: none;
}

.new-checkbox li.has-checked > ul {
  display: block;
}
.addDownicon li::before {
    content: "\25bc" !important;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.new-checkbox input[type=checkbox]').on("change", function() {
    var checked = this.checked,
      $li = $(this).parent();
    $li.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', checked).parent().toggleClass('has-checked', checked);

    $li.parentsUntil('.new-checkbox', 'li').each(function() {
      var $checks = $(this).find('ul input[type=checkbox]');
      $(this).children('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', !$checks.filter(':not(:checked)').length);

      $(this).toggleClass('has-checked', $checks.is(':checked'));
    });

  });


});
```

[for example like this](http://experiments.wemakesites.net/css3-treeview-with-multiple-node-selection.html)

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/vGyYyN)

and last thing: my checkboxes icon doesn't work how to fix it ?

Comment: Seems like it's working correctly to me.

Comment: How's this question different from [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35995624/dropdown-checkboxes-and-unchecked-parents-element)?

Comment: @ScottMarcus my demo link is not working correctly. if you clicked checkbox it will be checked (it's okey so far) but if I click label it hasn't to be checked.how to do it ?

Comment: @j08691 I'm trying to understand and I can't sleep before I will fix it :(

Comment: This is exactly the same as your last question. If you want to clarify any points raised or add additional examples or information, please edit the previous question.

Comment: My english is not enought to understand something that is why I wanted to explain clearly.no body understood last question.sorry