# how to disabled checkbox label to not checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

Hi since 2 days I'm working on this basic project to writes code again but last thing left I couldn't do it.

if you click label checkbox being checked.but this is the not thing that I want.if you click checkbox then checkbox has to be checked (I want to this just thoose which has got ul checkbox child - nested)

[you can see demo link on codepen](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/zqoNQg)

html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>No Title</title>
</head>
<body> 

    <div class="new-checkbox">
    <ul>
      <li class="hasUl">
        <input type="checkbox" id="input1">
        <label for="input1">kategori <strong>(1)</strong>
        </label>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input11">
            <label for="input11">kategori<strong>(11)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input12">
            <label for="input12">kategori <strong>(12)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input13">
            <label for="input13">kategori <strong>(13)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="input2">
        <label for="input2">kategori <strong>(2)</strong>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="hasUl">
        <input type="checkbox" id="input3">
        <label for="input3">kategori <strong>(3)</strong>
        </label>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input31">
            <label for="input31">kategori <strong>(31)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input32">
            <label for="input32">kategori <strong>(32)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input33">
            <label for="input33">kategori <strong>(33)</strong>
            </label>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="input331">
                <label for="input331">kategori <strong>(331)</strong>
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="input332">
                <label for="input332">kategori <strong>(332)</strong>
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="input333">
                <label for="input333">kategori <strong>(333)</strong>
                </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- new checkbox-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.anitur.com.tr/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" ></script>

</body>
</html>
```

css

```
.new-checkbox ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font: normal 11px/16px"Segoe UI", Arial, Sans-serif;
}
.new-checkbox ul:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.new-checkbox ul li {
  margin: 3px 0;
}
.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
.new-checkbox label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  content: "\00a0";
  display: inline-block;
  font: 16px/1em sans-serif;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 2px .25em 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: solid 1px #1375b3;
  color: #1375b3;
  opacity: .50;
}
.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  background: #fff;
  color: #1375b3;
  content: "\2714";
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) inset;
  opacity: 1;
}
.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.new-checkbox ul li:before {
  content: "\25b6";
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  color: #e74c3c;
  font-size: 8px;
  line-height: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li.parent.has-checked:before {
  content: "\25bc" !important;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  color: #e74c3c;
  font-size: 8px;
  line-height: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.new-checkbox li {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"][id]:checked ~ li::before {
  content: "\25bc";
}
.new-checkbox li ul {
  display: none;
}
.new-checkbox li.has-checked  > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.new-checkbox li:has(ul)').addClass('parent');

  $('.new-checkbox input[type=checkbox]:not(label)').on("change", function() {
    var checked = this.checked,
      $li = $(this).parent();
    $li.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', checked).parent().toggleClass('has-checked', checked);

    $li.parentsUntil('.new-checkbox', 'li').each(function() {
      var $checks = $(this).find('ul input[type=checkbox]');
      $(this).children('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', !$checks.filter(':not(:checked)').length);

      $(this).toggleClass('has-checked', $checks.is(':checked'));
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: So you want, if user clicks on label, then checkbox should not change, and should be only select if he clicks on checkbox. Am I right?

Comment: yes @Rajesh you right. but I want to this for thoose which has got nested checkbox

Comment: @Rajesh yes, it's related to [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35995624/dropdown-checkboxes-and-unchecked-parents-element/35996674#35996674) from yesterday. Look into the discussion around my solution.

Comment: @fortherest have you tried removing `for="input1"` from labels?

Comment: @Rajesh yes I tried but when if I clicked checkbox it's not being checked and if I clicked label sub checkbox is not displaying

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks more like CSS issue. Label is overlapping checkbox, hence click of checkbox is not working

Comment: @JohannesJander it must be way to do

Comment: @JohannesJander your way is great but if clicked checkbox I cannot checked it it's issue

Comment: @fortherest please update your codepen to the code from yesterday. Currently, the parent checkboxes with children are still checked if you click on them. Don't expect people to port your code.

Comment: no this is not expected just understanding to how to work and logically. my last updated: http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/zqoNQg

Comment: I tried every way but I messed up

Comment: I wrote a new code for jquery to do
$("label").on("click",function(){
    $(this).parent("li").find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",false);
  }); didn't work but I think this is the right way

Comment: @JohannesJander and I did it it's work but only if I click just checkbox it's not checking